# How to add multiple audio sources on a single game object?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, scripting

So I have a script that counts points when I collide with tagged game objects. I want the game to make a different sound when I hit different objects. So Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS1 : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text countText;
public Text winText;



private int count;


void Start()
{

    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
    winText.text = "";
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
}



void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 100;
        SetCountText();
    }


    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("minus300"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count - 300;
        SetCountText();
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
}

void SetCountText()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
    countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 5000)
        {
            winText.text = "Good Job!";
        }
    }


}
```

So how do I have a different sound for the PickUp object and the Minus300 object? Thank you!

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to also try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link to the audio sources in fields, and set them in the inspector in the Unity editor:

```
public class POINTS1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource pickUpAudio;
    public AudioSource minus300Audio;
    // ... Use pickUpAudio and minus300Audio instead of GetComponent<AudioSource>()
```

An alternative for more complex situations is to use [`GetComponents<AudioSource>()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponents.html) to get an array of `AudioSource` components, then iterate through them to find the right one. Not only is this less clear for your current situation, but it's also slower--although it may be necessary in some cases.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer, worked perfectly! Thanks :D